# Convert JSON dictionary into Bash one?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, dictionary

I am trying to receive output from an aws-cli command into Bash, and use it as an input to the second.
I successfully saved the output into the variable with [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533308/how-to-save-output-of-aws-cli-in-a-variable):

```
iid=$(aws ec2 run-instances ...)
```

and receive output like that:

```
{ "ImageId": "ami-0abcdef1234567890", "InstanceId": "i-1231231230abcdef0", "InstanceType": "t2.micro", ... }
```

I know that Bash since v4 [supports associative arrays](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) but I'm struggling converting one into one.

I tried to parse the dictionary in Bash but received error:

> must use subscript when assigning associative array

[This is because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55130064/911419) the right key syntax for Bash dicts is `=`, not `:`.

Finally I accessed the members by using [this marvelous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62622162/911419) with sed:

```
echo $iid|sed 's/{//g;s/}//g;s/"//g'|cut -d ':' -f2
```

**My question:** is there any standard way of creating a Bash dictionary from JSON or text besides regex? Best-practice?

Considering the snippet from the answer I used, the sed-approach can be very verbose and the verbosity increases exponentially with the number of keys/members:

```
for items in `echo $db|sed 's/{//;s/}//'`
do
        echo one${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f1`
        echo two${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f2`
        echo three${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f3`
        echo four${count} = `echo $items|sed 's/^.*\[//;s/\].*$//'|cut -d ',' -f4`
        ...
done
```

For simple dicts it is OK, but for the complex dictionaries with hundreds of keys and a big nesting level it is almost inapplicable.

Is there any unified approach for arbitrary dictionary?

P.S. I found answers about solving [the opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827679/accessing-python-dictionary-from-bash-script) (receiving Bash dict in Python), solving the task [through jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676527/transform-json-to-key-value-file-in-bash), creating dict [from Bash to Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975967/returning-a-dictionary-from-a-bash-function) and [from non-common input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382726/how-to-create-dictionary-using-shell-script) but nothing about specifically JSON. I prefer not to use jq and python and stick to the standard Bash toolset, most of the answers of [this collective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools) use 3rd-party tools. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I'd use `jq` to extract the relevant information from the json.

Comment: What are you looking to do with the array?

Comment: Accessing the members and modifying them (swapping, replacing)

Comment: @Suncatcher `jq` \(*if working from shell only*) is capable of doing all what you mention. Now if you have access to python or perl, manipulationg JSON objects from there, may be more natural than using the unique `jq`'s language, that can take a while to understand and master.

Comment: There is a significant difference between JSON objects and `bash` associative arrays. An associative array can only have *strings* as values, not other arrays. If you want to work with JSON, `bash` is the wrong language to use.

Comment: There is a Python package that wraps `libjq`, so you can use `jq` filters in Python in the cases where they *are* more natural to use.

Comment: `If you want to work with JSON, bash is the wrong language to use` Okay, clear. If it is non-natural, probably it's worth putting into answer to highlight that approach is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to turn your JSON object members into a Bash4+'s associative array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# shellcheck disable=SC2155 # Associative array declaration from JSON
declare -A assoc=$(
  jq -r '"(",(to_entries | .[] | "["+(.key|@sh)+"]="+(.value|@sh)),")"' \
  input.json
)

# Debug dump the Associative array declaration
typeset -p assoc
```

Sample output:

```sh
declare -A assoc=([InstanceId]="i-1231231230abcdef0" [InstanceType]="t2.micro" [ImageId]="ami-0abcdef1234567890" )
```